# Copy files from Linux server to local Windows machine in a BASH loop

Tags: linux, windows, bash, command-line

I have a list of names (`names_list`), each of them has a folder (`name`), inside there's another folder (`folder_to_copy`) that I want to copy from a Linux server to an external hard drive on a local Windows machine. I want to do this in a `while read` loop, as I have to iterate through several names. In `E:\me\`, an empty `$name` folder already exists. From putty, I tried:

```
while read name;
do
cp -R '/home/me/folder/'$name'/folder_to_copy' 'E:\me\'$name'\'
done < /home/me/names_list.txt
```

This creates a folder called `E:\me\'$name'\` (with some black dots in between `E` and `\`) in my working directory on the Linux server (which is not where I want them), with the desired files inside. I also tried this:

```
while read name;
do
cp -R '/home/me/folder/'$name'/folder_to_copy' 'myUsername@myIP:\E:\me\'$name'\'
done < /home/me/names_list.txt
```

Which, similarly, created a folder called `myUsername@myIP:\E:\me\'$name'\`. If I change from \ to /, it throws an error (cannot create directory). I guess I'm messing with paths...

Comment: I suggest using rsync for this kind of task, its designed to do so :).

Comment: You can't copy like this in linux. First mount windows share drive in linux and then copy the files. Example  mkdir /mnt/win_share ;  mount -t cifs  //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share

Comment: You could do something close to that using scp (cp using SSH).  But if you want to copy only differences, rsync is the king!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! rsync seems definitely worth trying. I found out the server is mounted on my local Windows machine (I can access it through the file explorer) and this means I can use R, where I already have scripts to copy files looping through folders.